# Match using predicate function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parsing

**Notice**: This is my first question on StackOverflow (although I've answered before). If you think I haven't clarified something, feel free to tell me in the comments.

You may have heard of the `String.prototype.match()` function in JavaScript, which searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object. Here's an example:

```js
var str = "(list 1 2 foo (list nice 3 56 989 asdasdas))"
console.log(str.match(/\d+/g)) //=>["1", "2", "3", "56", "989"]
```

However, I need a match-like method that inputs a **function** in JavaScript. This input function would take in a substring of the original string, and output a boolean telling if the substring is a valid match or not. Here's an example of the intended behavior

```js
    function standardFunc(substr) {
       return parseFloat(substr) !== NaN;
    }

    var str = "(list 1 2 foo (list nice 3 56 989 asdasdas))"
    console.log(str.match(standardFunc)) //=>["1", "2", "3", "56", "989"]
```

Is there an easy way to emulate this behavior in JavaScript?

Comment: You say that "the input function would take in a *substring of the original string* - but how does the input function know where to split the string for the substring? What if the developer wanted to split by '*' characters instead of spaces for example?

For this reason I think keeping splitting and filtering separate is best.

Answer (score 3):

If you can set or somehow identify the boundaries of which sorts of substrings get matched, it's possible. For example, here, every match looks to begin and end at a word boundary:

```js
function standardFunc(str) {
   return !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(str))
}

const str = "(list 1 2 foo (list nice 3 56 989 asdasdas))";
for (const match of str.matchAll(/\b.+?\b/g)) {
  if (standardFunc(match[0])) {
    console.log(match[0]);
  }
}
```

Note you'll need to use `Number.isNaN` instead of using `!== NaN`.

If you're not looking for a general solution, but just a solution to this particular problem, solve this with a regex alone. Match digits followed by an optional decimal point and more digits:

```js
function standardFunc(str) {
   return !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(str))
}

const str = "123.03 (list 1 2 foo (list nice 3 56 989 asdasdas))";
console.log(
  str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Also, I'm looking for the general solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `Array.prototype.filter` method after converting the string to an array:

```js
var stg = "(list 1 2 foo (list nice 3 56 989 asdasdas))";

var stgAsArray = stg.split(' ');

var numbersFromString = stgAsArray.filter(word => !Number.isNaN(parseFloat(word)));

console.log(numbersFromString)

console.log(numbersFromString.join(' '));
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but it only works if the input is seperated by whitespace.

Comment: The sample only works if the input is separated by white space. The conversion of the string to an array could be modified to act however you wanted. The input will need to be separated by something or else 55 could be 55 or 5 and 5 who knows?